# How to change text with andengine without to lag the rendering?

Tags: android, text, andengine

I want to introduce a count down in my game. I'm using a code like this:

In `onCreateResources()`

```java
this.font = FontFactory.create(this.getFontManager(), this.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR, Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD), 48);
this.font.load();
```

In `onCreateScene()`

```java
this.countDownText = new Text(0, 0, this.font, "300", "300".length(), this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
this.scene.attachChild(countDownText);

this.remain = 300;
this.timerHandler = new TimerHandler(1 / 10f, true, new ITimerCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
        remain--;
        countDownText.setText(remain + "");
    }
});
this.scene.registerUpdateHandler(timerHandler);
```

I found information about this problem and differents solutions that doesn't work for me:

- Use `ChangableText`: *This class is not longer in Andengine.*
- Preload the characters: *This doesn't work for me.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ChangeableText is Text: [link](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/issues/46)

> "Text has all functionality of the old ChangeableText."

Comment: This does not address the problem of lag when changing text, which was the question after all.